# How to create a 3-Dimensional data.frame from multiple Excel files in R

Tags: r, excel

I have the following code example:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
N <- 5 #number of datasets to pull data from
ind <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2015")

A <- array(rep(1, 91*144*5), dim=c(91,144,5))

for (k in seq_along(ind)) {
   A <- read_excel(paste0("~R/data", ind[k], ".xlsx"), range="B3:EO94")
}
```

I know that this is not reproducible due to inability to upload data. The above code captures my thought process in what I am trying to do. I want to create a matrix `A(i,j,k)` where `i` and `j` are rows and columns, respectively, from the `k` excel files. So in my case, `k` is the years in `ind`. I have those 5 excel files and they have identical dimensions.

What I want out of this process is the ability to take a particular set of `i,j` and create a new vector that has a length=`k`, although this is not the question I am asking here. For context, `i` and `j` are longitude and latitude and `k` is year.

Comment: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)its way easier for others to find a solution to your problem. By defintion,a MRE is **not** putting your whole code and database in the question but creating an example with as little code and data as needed to replicate the problem! The MRE will make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question.

Comment: This is honestly all I have at this point, I have no idea what to do next

Comment: if all entires are of the same class you could make an array with 3 dimensions.

Comment: @GordonShumway that is exactly what I am trying to do I just don't know how to

Comment: @Brennan I'm not sure what's going on in your loop. You are assigning k a string each time but not using it in the loop (your file name is a static string). Also, you are just overwriting `A` each time, when you want A to be a 3D array receiving a different 2D slice in each cycle of the loop. So you should declare `A` as a 91 * 150(ish) * 5 array ahead of the loop, change the for to `for(k in seq_along(ind))`, change `A` to `A[,,k]` and `"~R/data[k]"` to `paste0("~R/data", ind[k])`

Comment: @AllanCameron Your comment definitely suffices as an answer thank you! If you post it as one I will gladly accept

Comment: I get the following error: Error in A[, , k] <- read_excel(paste0("~/R/data",  : 
  incorrect number of subscripts

Comment: @AllanCameron I updated the code in the question

Comment: @Brennan can you try `A[,,k] <- as.matrix(read_excel(...`. If that doesn't work, try `A <- as.matrix(` and check `dim(A)` after your code has run

Comment: @AllanCameron when doing A <- as.matrix(rep(0,91*144*5), dim=c(91,144,5)) I get dim(A) [1] 65520. The as.matrix(read_excel(... gives me the same error message as before

Comment: Sorry, I mean when you read the excel file directly into a variable, are the dims c(91,144)?

Comment: @AllanCameron Oh like any given one? I run the code: B <- read_excel(paste0("~R/data", ind[1], ".xlsx"), range = "B3:EO94") and then dim(B) gives me [1] 91 144 so yeah

Comment: That's strange - you should be able to write B to A[,,1] in that case? Your other option is to make A an empty list and store each sheet to A[k] in the list. You can then do array(unlist(A), dim = c(91, 144, 5))

Comment: @AllanCameron Your latter suggestion worked perfectly, weird that the other didn't. Thank you very much! if you want to succinctly write that out as an answer I will accept to clear it from unanswered questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write the sheets to a list, then create an array from the unlisted contents:

```r
library(readxl)

ind <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2015")
A <- list()

for (k in seq_along(ind)) {
   A[k] <- read_excel(paste0("~R/data", ind[k], ".xlsx"), range="B3:EO94")
}

result <- array(unlist(A), dim=c(91,144,5))
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Will the A[k] import the excel files with `i` rows and `j` columns? It does not seem to properly match up with the excel file

Comment: Disregard my comment, I will ask a new question as it is more involved